# How to use SVG Icons in Semantic-UI

Tags: svg, font-awesome, semantic-ui

In the [documentation](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html) for Semantic-UI Icons, the framework purports to "include a complete port of [Font Awesome 5.0.8](https://fontawesome.com)" which supports SVG icons and Semantic-UI even includes in the assets an `icons.svg` file. I have searched and found no information in the Semantic-UI documentation as to how to actually use SVG icons. I have tried supplying the file as an argument to the `@font-face` property, but that is not supported by most modern browsers. Does anybody know how to use the SVG icons that Semantic-UI purports to support?

P.S. If anybody is wondering why I need the SVG icons, it is to work around a bug in IE11. I am dealing with a network of users on Windows 10 with the group policy to "Block Untrusted Fonts" enabled, and IE11 does not properly allow my website to serve `.woff`, `.woff2`, `.ttf`, or `.eot` files to the user. This is a confirmed issue with IE11 and the only workaround that is feasible for this project may be to use SVG icons.

Comment: `<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/js/all.js"></script> ` Just add this icon pack and you should be able to use it without any problems. Here you have a link to font awesome website: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=svg-with-js

Comment: @JakubMuda This is using fontawesome separate from Semantic-UI, which is not what I asked. I can do that just fine, but doing so causes numerous UI issues when trying to replace Semantic Icons with fontawesome icons as Semantic doesn't seem to understand how to manage them in certain components causing bugs. 

My question is how to use SVG icons that are purportedly provided with Semantic-UI, not how to get them elsewhere.